# RAS Algorithm generate Random Matrix

Tags: r

Trying to generate a random matrix with constraints on the sums of rows and columns, and zeros on the diagonal.

So far, by using `Ipfp` function in the `mipfp` package, I could generate a random matrix with constraints on sums of rows and columns, but still can not get the diagonal equal to 0 done.

```
InitialM <- array(1,dim=c(5,5))
SumOfRows <- c(40, 60, 20, 10, 10)
SumOfCols <- c(30, 30, 60, 10, 10)
TargetData<- list(SumOfRows, SumOfCols)
Target.list <- list(1,2)
RandomMatrix <- Ipfp(InitialM, Target.list, TargetData, 
   iter=100, tol=1e-10)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any evidence that this algorithm is flexible enough to achieve your goal ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want to do, you simply need to set the diagonal of the initial matrix `InitialM` to 0:

```
InitialM <- array(1,dim=c(5,5))
for(i in 1:5) {
  InitialM[i,i] <- 0
}

SumOfRows <- c(40, 60, 20, 10, 10)
SumOfCols <- c(30, 30, 60, 10, 10)
TargetData<- list(SumOfRows, SumOfCols)
Target.list <- list(1,2)
RandomMatrix <- Ipfp(InitialM, Target.list, TargetData, 
                     iter=100, tol=1e-10)
```

As a result, the final `RandomMatrix` will have zeros on the diagonal and the constraints on the sums of rows and columns will match.